# override all inhereted css properties on element, effectively killing all styling

Tags: css, inheritance, overriding, styling

I only have access to the CSS file in this case so do not give any other solutions that involve changing HTML, javascript, etc.

I have a class who I want to wipe out styling on for testing. The default styling is creeping in and causing an issue. To debug I just want to clear ALL styling for an element. The problem is that I don't know what all properties may be on every element from the default, it's lots of different things in different cases. I just want to say that for a given class, there is no styling. Is this possible?

Comment: Sadly, there is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried a css reset such as Eric Myer's? - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Too bad to hear there is no real way to do this, but using this should at least help me a little. Thanks!